# Why do I get this error in php?

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to loop through couple of links from my database, to check the header status of each one

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("tracker", $con);

$result=mysql_query
        ("

        SELECT id,ziel_url FROM wm_mapping WHERE ziel_url LIKE '%websale7%'");

if (!$result)
{
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$rows=array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$fp = fopen('url.csv', 'a+');
$csv=array();
foreach ($rows as $row){

        file_get_contents($row['ziel_url']);
        $response =$http_response_header[29];
        $csv[] = trim($row['id']).','.trim($row['ziel_url']).','.trim($response);


}
file_put_contents('url.csv', implode("\r\n", $csv), FILE_APPEND);
```

and for the line  `$response =$http_response_header[29];` i I get an error Undefined offset:

What does it mean?

Comment: error within [] try---- foreach ($http_response_header as $header)
{
    echo $header . "<br>\n";
}

Comment: It means you do not have a 29th element in your `$http_response_header` variable, which is also not defined anywhere.

Comment: checkout **print_r($http_response_header);** May be you will get the solution.

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* for database access, it's all but deprecated and contains some serious security weaknesses and is unsuitable for communicating with MySQL 5 or newer.

Comment: so $http_response_header can not be used as I used!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response =isset($http_response_header[29])?$http_response_header[29]:SOMETHING_ELSE;
```

Comment: Because it's automatically created (imho it's a horrible solution/implementation from the developers of php) and inserted into the current scope after using an http stream like: file_get_contents('http://site.com/'))..

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there aren't 30 elements in the `$http_response_header` array. Try looking at the array contents with `var_dump($http_response_header);` to see which element you want to use.